# change content of html on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to achieve the same effect as this [website](https://www.chelseacollective.com/home).

You will notice that the url changes and the content changes when you scroll, however when I inspect the requests being made in the console I cannot see a new AJAX request being made to get the new html content. I cannot figure out how this content is being loaded.

It appears the "page change" is just a javascript scrolling effect, and the javascript also changes the URL. If you notice, go to the about section and refresh that url, and the page isn't found.

Any guidance on how this can be achieved would be greatly appreciated. I have read through the javascript source code on the page, but as it is minified I am still struggling to understand how it all works. Perhaps I should be using html5's history state.

My current project is set up like this:

[image]

The index.html file looks like this:

```
<body>       
    <header>
        <img src="homeLogo.png">
    </header>
    <div id="scene">
        <h3>Home page</h3>
        <div class="bgImage"></div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        Footer 
    </footer>
</body>
```

the tress/index.html file looks like this:

```
    <body>       
        <header>
            <img src="homeLogo.png">
        </header>
            <div id="scene">
               <h3>Trees</h3>
                 <div class="bgImage trees"></div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
            Footer 
        </footer>
    </body>
```

urban/index.html is the same as tress/index.html apart from the div within the div with id `scene`.

Based on how the project is set up I am wondering how I can update the content page with the different html files.

Comment: iframe? change src of iframe on scroll in accordance to what you want. whether it be trees/index.html or urban/index.html

Comment: FYI, unminifiers such as `unminify.com` would help you for minified javascripts (even css and htmls too)

Comment: I know this might not be on the topic of the question *(my apologies if it isn't)*, but I would just like to point out that https://www.chelseacollective.com/ is a brilliantly designed website, I mean just look at it... The design is just beautiful. Also @jackjop thanks for the link to http://unminify.com, appreciate it.

Comment: @phantom check out parallax scrolling. here's a demo (with a variety of effects) https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/parallax-scroll-effect/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the History API, specifically at the function:

```
   window.history.pushState({ your_data:"whatever"}, "title", newUrl);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

There are excellent third party libraries that can help you easily build a cross-browser solution, although modern browsers follow the standard decently.

The rest of your problem is just dynamically adding content, that may come from an ajax request or not.

Comment: ok, but how would I update the content based on the project layout above?can this be done without an ajax request?

Comment: either you use a `XmlHttpRequest` to load files, or you load all content in a JS file then render it incrementally as the user scrolls

Comment: could you explain how to load all content in a JS file?

Comment: You just create an array, where each element in the array is a text page. Then you render every string in the array as the user scrolls.

Comment: @rupps so would this stray from the way the project is set up above. In this case would I need to have these files on a server?